# When i connect my database in R it doesn´t list all my tables

Tags: r, sqlite

So i started using R and i would like to make some analysis in a database that i have on my computer (.db) but i´m not able to make the connection.

here is my code:

```
library("RSQLite")
db<-dbConnect(SQLite(),dbname="Astraud.db")
dbListTables(db)
```

it doesn´t show an error,actually the output is:

`character(0)`

I mean it supposed to show me all the tables that i have. But i doesn´t.

I´ve been researching all day trying to find a good tutorial that explains how to use "sqlite" in R but so far i haven´t found anyone, so if you guys could reccomend me one, i will aprecciate it.

THANKS!!!!

Comment: Are you sure that Astraud.db has any data in it?    What is the size of the file Astraud.db ?

Comment: Is your working directory correct? Does `file.exists("Astraud.db")` return true? If yes, does `file.info("Astraud.db")` show the file size you are expecting, or something smaller (like size 0)?

Comment: BTW,  have you tried [This Tutorial](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/vignettes/RSQLite.html) ? It seems simple yet helpful.

Comment: @r2evans  I solved it, i wasn´t using the right path. Thanks guys. One more question, how can i use all the commands like "plot", "summary", etc. in a specific table or column.

Comment: WasabiPoint, I suggest you look at the tutorial that G5W suggested, and look up some SQL tutorials as well. You can't run `plot` on a database, you must first execute a query to download the data (or some subset of it) into memory, at which point it is "just" a normal `data.frame`.